# Can't reverse an array with double pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, double, reverse

I am having some problems with a school assignment where we are suppose to create our own iterator and use it to reverse the elements in an array.
If it was only single pointer I think I would manage it but this is with double pointer and confusing as hell...

Here is the reverse code:

```
void reverse(T start, T end)
{
    T temp = start;
    while(start < end)
    {
        *temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = *temp;
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}
```

and here is the problem because when I point `temp` to `start`, `temp` gets `start`'s value and address.. But when I point `start` to `end` well then `start` AND `temp` changes naturally.

I can't figure out for the life of me how to fix this....

Here is the call I make in my main:

```
int a[5] = {5, 12, 1, 6, 9};
Itterfunctions<int*> itt;
int *b = a;
itt.reverse(b, b+4);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: You want to **copy** the temporary character. `char temp = *start;`

Comment: Also, probably `int *` not required in `Itterfunctions<int*> itt;`

Comment: temp points all the time to start, which means every time you assign something to temp you will change start. I would make temp an int instead of a pointer.

Comment: I never assign anything to temp except for the start. And it has to be a pointer since its supposed to be generic so i can handle all sorts of things with my reverser.

Comment: `last` should be a better name than `end`, `end` generally refer to a iterator which point to "invalid" data just after the last element.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

sat with this problem for two days and when i finally decided to post it here I solved it.

This is how:

```
void reverse(T start, T end)
{
    unsigned temp = *start;
    while(start < end)
    {
        temp = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = temp;
        ++start;
        --end;
    }
}
```

I made the temp unsigned instead of T. But im unsure if this will work for our own objects such as spheres we have created and so on... does anyone know?

Comment: Using `unsigned int` will work only when `*start` is a `unsigned int`. if you use c++11, you may use `auto temp = *start;` instead. Moreover `std::swap` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
*temp = *start;
*start = *end;
*end = temp;
```

use

```
std::swap(*start, *end);
```

currently your temp variable point to `start` and so you use `start` as temp location and it is not.

Note also that generally `end` is not used for the iterator which points to the last element.

Comment: It is easy to write your own. `template<typename T> void myswap(T& lhs, T& rhs) {T tmp(lhs); lhs = rhs; rhs = tmp; }` (you may have better version with move semantic).